# How to create common menu to all Activity in android studio.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, menuitem, android-menu

I want create to four common menu(Master Page)one Activity by using all activities like tab activity, i have using select,update,delete,search menu this all come to commonly all activities how to do some one tell me please

Comment: You can use one menu on Main activity and show other content in fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an activity with menu ( Drawer menu ), and create multi fragment by fragment transaction or viewpager inside activity. All fragment inside this activity have this menu.

Comment: This is clearly example: http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/05/android-basic-training-course-combining.html

Comment: this tab is showing top i want to bottom side button,button  i clicked the button the function is call to fragment

Comment: if you want the tab on bottom side, in layout file, find Tablayout and move it to under viewpager

Answer (score 0):

You can create drawer menu and then use fragment. Then you can have all the menus on these fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You try to Common Activity put  and call to Fragement